# mount a cifs share without root/fstab

Tags: linux, java, network-shares, samba, cifs

Hello is it possible to mount a samba share without root privileges?

Currently I have a java program that needs to access a smb share. (it will index every file on the smb share and will create some pdfs)

Since the IP or the DNS name of the share could change (it should be changeable on the interface) i can't put it in the fstab file.

Also i don't want to run my application as a root user, since that would be really bad.
Are there any other things that I could do, that ALL users in a linux system could mount cifs shares without putting the mount point into the fstab file?

Comment: You can user your applications with your underprivileged user with help from the `uid` field, but I bet you'll need root access to be able to mount it.

Comment: Perhaps your Java program could use a library like `jCIFS` instead of mounting the share at OS level?

Comment: most systems can mount samba in userland via FUSE, and will mount the share within the users home. what distro are you using, and what command are you using to mount it?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

this old post of mine resurfaced to my attention recently. The part about finding samba shares on the LAN can be gretaly improved, as follows.

First use an *nmap script* to find the shares:

```
sudo nmap -oX - -sU -sS --script smb-enum-shares.nse -p U:137,T:139 192.168.1.0/24
```

(if your LAN is not 192.168.1.0/24, please modify accordingly). Notice the use of the option *-oX -* which sends output to the screen **in XML format**, the most suitable one for scripting.

Now process the output with *xmllint*:

```
xmllint --xpath "//table/@key" -
```

This locates the value of the *key* attribute in all *table* nodes which have one, producing output in the form:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "//table/@key" filename
  key="\\192.168.1.1\IPC$" key="\\192.168.1.1\ClassicalMusic" key="\\192.168.1.1\print$" key="\\192.168.1.94\IPC$" key="\\192.168.1.94\RockMusic" key="\\192.168.1.94\VariousMusic" key="\\192.168.1.94\print
```

Notice one annoying feature: versions of *xmllint* before 2.9.9 cannot separate different matches with a new line, read [this answer on a sister site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48311523/2796243). If you need more info on *xpath* or *xmllint* , you may read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint), respectively.

If you already know the share name, and you are positive there *no white spaces* in its name, you can combine all of the above to obtain the share name and address, as

```
sudo nmap -oX - -sU -sS --script smb-enum-shares.nse -p U:137,T:139 192.168.1.0/24 |\
xmllint --xpath "//table/@key" - |\
sed 's/ /\n/g' |\
grep ShareName
```

which yields something like

```
key="\\192.168.1.1\ClassicalMusic"
```

**cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc**

You cannot escape being root if you wish to mount a resource for all users: after all, you are trespassing on other users' system configuration, and only root is allowed to do that.

Despite all of your constrains, you can still do this. You will have to write a shell script that finds the share to be mounted, then mounts it. I will outline it for you (sorry, I am in a rush).

1. This command

   ```
   sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
   ```

(assuming your LAN is 192.168.1.0, substitute the appropriate numbers for your LAN) will return a list of all active pcs.

2. feed that list to this command, one at a time,

   ```
   nmblookup -A 192.168.1.72
   ```

and it will return the NetBios name of the pc in question.

3. query the existence of Samba shares with this command:

   ```
   smbclient -L net_bios_name_just-found -N
   ```

this will give you a list of all shares on this system, using the netBios name you just found. Amidst these results, you will find the samba share you need.

At this point, you know IP address and NetBios name of the host pc, and of course the name of the Samba share you are interested in. You can now mount the share as root, as you like.

If you script these commands, you can:

1. execute it at will as root just to test it;
2. insert it in crontab (as root, crontab -e) with the follwoing line:

   ```
   @boot /home/my_name/bin/my_special_script
   ```

having made sure that my_special_script is executable. The share will be mounted then every time you boot.

Cheers, gotta go.